# Android - best storage method to store objects (database or json/internal storage)

Tags: java, android, storage

I'm new to Android development. I want to do a small app that need to store quotes from famous people. I'm going to use an Object quote to store each quote. The object will be simple and only use Strings. 
I want the user to be able to add quotes, but I want them to be stored so they can be saved the next time the user open the app.

I've seen a lot of questions about how to store data and they usually give you lists of available technology. I'm wondering what are the common practices among experienced developers, what are the common use for each technology.

I know it's possible to use a database. But since I only want to store a list of quotes object I'm wondering if that wouldn't be too much.

I could store it in a file in the internal storage. But then how do I store it? Should a store it in json format and every time the user start the app I simply use the json to recreate the list of quotes.

I'm not sure which way would more practical or even if using json would be effective.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: It would be better if your question was about the tradeoffs of each approach and how they relate to your specific application, not popularity.  Popularity won't help you achieve a good fit to your application unless there really is only one viable way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I modified the question

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend you to use Shared Preferences since those are intended for very short data, say 100 kb to 1 MB. In you case you can store quotes either in an sqlite database or in a file. (One that suits your need). You can test between how much  time does it take to write your quote to a file and to a database, both are good choices. In both cases you should create a wrapper class and use it according to your needs, which will make the working convenient.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought for the Shared Preferences. I've never store data in a file, should I just have list of object then, turn it into a json String and then store the string in a file?

Comment: As I said, both are good choices. The thing you want to know is, which method suits perfectly to your application. If storing in file satisfies your need, then absolutely go ahead. Although, using a database is not a bad choice IMHO.